# searching for file unix script

Tags: bash, unix

My script is as shown:
it searches for directories and provides info on that directory, however I am having trouble setting exceptions.

```
if [ -d "$1" ];
then
  directories=$(find "$1" -type d | wc -l)
  files=$(find "$1" -type f | wc -l)
  sym=$(find "$1" -type l | wc -l)

  printf "%s %'d\n" "Directories" $directories
  printf "%s %'d\n" "Files" $files
  printf "%s %'d\n" "Sym links" $sym
  exit 0
else
  echo "Must provide one argument"
  exit 1
fi
```

How do I make it so that if I search for a file it tells me that a directory needs to be inputted? I'm stuck on it, I've tried test commands but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your shebang in the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I get correct results from your script if I add it:

```
Directories 1,991
Files 13,363
Sym links 0
```

You may have to set the correct execution permissions also `chmod +x scriptname.sh`?

Entire script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ];
        then
                echo "Please provide at least one argument!"
                exit 1
elif [ -d "$1" ];
        then
                directories=$(find "$1" -type d | wc -l)
                files=$(find "$1" -type f | wc -l)
                sym=$(find "$1" -type l | wc -l)
                printf "%s %'d\n" "Directories" $directories
                printf "%s %'d\n" "Files" $files
                printf "%s %'d\n" "Sym links" $sym
                exit 0
        else
                echo "This is a file, not a directory"
                exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I want a message to say something along the lines of "not a directory" when i search for the file, where would that printf/echo go? Im really new to scripting.

Comment: But the script is not searching for a file - please five an example of what you want to find where. I mean you could simply use „find / -name (filename)“, then you wouldn‘t need the rest of the script, or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: So the script searches for a directory, if the directory exists, it lists some properties like the number of files in the directory, sym links etc.

Comment: If the user doesnt enter an argument/sirectory name at all, the "Must provide one argument" kicks in

Comment: I want it if the argument entered is a file name, it asks for the user to enter a directory with a simple echo